# Plot3D Question Involving Double Integral Taking a Long Time to Execute

Tags: plotting

I'm trying to plot f(a,b) over [0,2]x[0,2] using Plot3D. See attached. I terminate after letting it run for 10 minutes because I get no output and no error messages. Should it take longer than this? I'm able to evaluate the function without a problem but, for some reason, I'm unable to plot it. I believe the syntax is correct. The expression involves an improper integral which definitely converges.

[image]

Comment: (1) People here generally like users to post code as *Mathematica* code instead of just images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you. You may find [the meta Q&A, How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site,](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful. (2) You're recomputing the integral for every point computed for the plot. It's probably better to compute the integral first.

Answer (score 5):

```
$Version

(* "13.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

int1[a_, y_] = Integrate[Exp[-(x - a)^2/2], {x, 0, y}]

(* Sqrt[π/2] (Erf[a/Sqrt[2]] - Erf[(a - y)/Sqrt[2]]) *)

int2[a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ] := 
 1/(2 Pi) NIntegrate[Exp[-(y - b)^2/2] int1[a, y], {y, 0, Infinity}]

Plot3D[int2[a, b], {a, 0, 2}, {b, 0, 2},
 AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

[image]